# How can I split a dictionary by commas and make a correct csv file with it in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to make a csv file that contains a dictionary:

```
    dict={"Steps" : [], "x" : []}
```

The problem is that the code of making csv is below and the data in "Steps" and "x" is this: Steps = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc...}, x = {-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}
I want to separate those numbers by commas and write down those values in the columns under the variables (Steps, x) in csv.

| Steps | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 |
| etc. | etc. |

I've tried different things, like "delimiter" but didn't make everything right.

Can anyone help me?

```
   def csvEXP(): #csv export
       with open('RW_database.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as csvfile:
           writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, dict)
            
           # write the header
           writer.writeheader()
    
           # write the data
           for row in dict["Steps"]:
               

           writer.writerow(dict)
```

Result of this code is this:

```
|Steps|x|
|-|-|
|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|
|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|
|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|
|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...}|
|etc.|etc.|
```

The WHOLE DICTIONARY.

Comment: Just as an FYI, json might be a better option

Comment: 1) A CSV file will not have a `dict`, it is  text format. 2) This `{-1, 5, 2, 6, 73, 23, etc...} ` is not a `dict` it is a `set` and that does not exist in CSV either. Anything you put in a CSV file will be a string so you will need to deal with that when retrieving it.

Comment: if you use `for`-loop to get `row` then you should write `row` instead fo `dict` in line `writer.writerow(row)`. OR you should use `writerows()` with char `s` at the end - to write all without using `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to make complex multi-level functions for this task. a simple loop and file I/O is sufficient:

```py
dictionary = {"steps" : [1, 2, 3, 5], "x" : [-1, 5, 2, 6]}

file = open("data.csv", "w")
file.write("steps,x\n")
for index in range(len(dictionary["steps"])):
    file.write(str(dictionary["steps"][index]) + "," + str(dictionary["x"][index]) + "\n")

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`csv.DictWriter` could be useful if you would have list of dictionares

```
import csv

data = [
    {"Steps": 1, "x": -1 },
    {"Steps": 2, "x":  5 },
    {"Steps": 3, "x":  2 },
    {"Steps": 4, "x":  6 },
    {"Steps": 5, "x": 73 },
]    

headers = ['Steps','x']

with open('RW_database.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)

    writer.writeheader()

    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

But for your data you could use normal `csv.writer` and `zip()`

```
import csv

data = {
    "Steps" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "x" : [-1, 5, 2, 6, 73]
}

headers = ['Steps','x']

with open('RW_database.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in zip(data['Steps'], data['x']):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Or you could use `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Steps" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "x" : [-1, 5, 2, 6, 73]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```